# Why is it "Shaun the Sheep" but "Peter Rabbit"? Or Pepa Pig, but Dorothy the Dinosaur

Tags: definite-articles, epithets, postpositive

Epithets. 
I can add some more examples, for example:
Charles the Great, Charles the Rash, Edward the Confessor
BUT
The Brothers Grimm, the Emperor Jones

What is the rule or difference in meaning when post-positive or pre-positive adjectives are used?

What is difference between Peter Rabbit and Peter the Rabbit?

Comment: Sinbad the Sailor, Barnacle Bill the Sailor, Popeye the Sailor**man**. They is what they is.

Comment: Kermit the Frog, but Fozzie Bear ...

Answer (score 5):

In the most general sense, "Peter the Rabbit" would imply you're talking about a rabbit named Peter, while "Peter Rabbit" would imply the character's surname is Rabbit. The character "Shaun the Sheep" is a sheep named Shaun, while Peppa Pig's is a pig who ALSO has the surname "Pig". Likewise, Charles the Great did not have "Great" in his legal name, while the Brothers Grimm shared the surname Grimm.

Answer (score 1):

The answer above is technically right, but the legal surname of a talking animal is not a terribly important matter.

So, I suspect that many such choices are likely made based on how easily the result rolls off a tongue.  Dora the Explorer works.  Need the "the" to break up those vowels. Dora Dinosaur sounds fine though.  (So they got that wrong...err...).  Shaun Sheep would sound awful: like one long, saliva-heavy non-verbal noise emission.  The "the" is vital.

Comment: The first three examples are monarchs, and it's traditional to precede epithets applied to monarchs with 'the'. A writer who invents an animal character can give it whatever name seems good to them; there is no 'rule'.