# Article the with characters' names

Tags: definite-articles

Why do we use article 'the' with names of fairytale characters?
For example, Peg the Hen, Fuzzy the Hamster, Cheeky the parakeet?

Comment: It is no mystery.  ‘The’ is used for specification.  So I ask “How much is that doggy in the window?”. You ask “Which one?”. I answer “The one with the waggle tail.”.  Someone in a mediaeval village might tell you “””That’s Jack the miller.’. Eventually it turned into Jack Miller!.  Down through history, famous people have be given adjectival titles:  Pompey the Great, Ivan the Terrible, Ethelred the unready, Jack the Ripper, Elizabeth the second.  Named fairytale and fiction figures are just an extension of that:  the Cheshire cat, the severn dwarfs, the beast, the Pooh.

Comment: Not always; c.f. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Peppa_Pig_characters It's one way of identifying characters in fantasy stories involving animals of different species.

Comment: @Tuffy — You may not have noticed (if you are on a mobile device) that there is a specific injunction not to use comments to answer questions. Your answer seems to me quite good, but it should be made into an answer.

Comment: @David I suppose I felt it was worth saying something simple, but that it was, au fond too opinion based to qualify as an answer alla ELU.

Comment: @Tuffy — No. I would say it was based on argument and used precedent. I was thinking of an answer on these lines myself, but was busy and felt it needed historical evidence. Was Edward the Confessor so called in his lifetime or only in more recent times, for example?  Piers Plowman is an early counter-example.

Comment: @David Interestingly, as I didn’t point out, the Latin for Pompey the Great did not have ‘the’ for the simple reason that Latin had no definite article!  But I must admit, having checked, prompted by your question, and have to admit that Anglo-Saxon did not use a definite article either!  He was:  Aethelred Unraed.  So bang goes that example!

Comment: @Tuffy — I was going to say I also needed to check foreign examples. What about French surnames: Legrand, Lebrun, Leblanc?

Comment: @David Hmmm.  Now I can’t write an answer because it will have been a joint effort!

Comment: @Tuffy. Sure you can.  I don’t mind your using my input.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is it "Shaun the Sheep" but "Peter Rabbit"? Or Pepa Pig, but Dorothy the Dinosaur](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/409404/why-is-it-shaun-the-sheep-but-peter-rabbit-or-pepa-pig-but-dorothy-the-din)

Comment: They're epithets. Consider: Richard the Lionheart, Ivan the Terrible, Æthelred the Unready.

Answer (score 1):

It is no mystery. ‘The’ is used for specification. So I ask “How much is that doggy in the window?”. You ask “Which one?”. I answer “**The** one with the waggly tail.” (i.e. **the doggy**with **the**waggly tail).

Someone in a mediaeval village might tell you "That’s Jack **the** miller.". Eventually it turned into Jack Miller!. Down through history, famous people have be given adjectival titles: Pompey **the** Great, Ivan **the** Terrible, Ethelred **the** unready, Jack **the** Ripper, Elizabeth **the** second. Named fairytale and fiction figures are just an extension of that: **the** Cheshire cat, **the** severn dwarfs, **the** beast, Winnie **the** Pooh.

I am not aware of a technical name for this usage.  It is, in any case far from universal, as Kate Bunting points out in a comment.

This has not always been so and is not so in all languages.  So Pompey **the** Great did not have a definite article in the original Latin, which does not have a definite article.  He was just called Pompeius Magnus (or, more strictly, POMPEIVS MAGNVS); and the Anglo-Saxon king, Ethelred had no definite article, either:  he was Aethelred Unraed.  David in his comment has pointed out how the use of a specifying definite article of this kind is detectable in Norman French names:  Legrand, Leblanc, etc...  I am not aware that such a use of the article is met in modern French writing.

If we wanted a name for this usage, we might call it the definite article *of specification*.  But why add to the list of technical terms, already sufficiently long?